# How would I calculate the quotient of 'churn' with the previous month's 'active'?

Tags: sql, sisense

Trying to get the churn rate, obviously. Getting the quotient within each month would be easy but incorrect.

Frankly, I'm totally lost on this one. Would it make more sense to reorganize the output first?

[image]

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text. What is your definition of “churn”? Please provide the DDL of the table(s) involved, sample data and the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I put your data in a table variable (which is SQL Server) to write the query. The actual `SELECT` statement I wrote should work in all RDBMSs - I think it is all ANSI standard SQL. You didn't mention what data you wanted to see, nor did you mention what should happen in MONTH 1 where there is no previous month, but hopefully you will be able to get your final query from seeing this.

To do it, `JOIN` the table to itself. I use two aliases, `d1` and `d2`. For `d1` I want to find CHURN and `d2` I want to find ACTIVE. Also, the MONTHS of `d2` should be one less than the MONTHS of `d1`. Finally, since I declared the SUM column as an `INT`, I multiply it by 1.0 to force it to an approximate data type, otherwise the division would come back as zero or a truncated `INT` (since it is integer division).

```sql
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    [ID]               INT,
    [MONTHS]           INT,
    [THIS_MONTH_VALUE] VARCHAR(10),
    [SUM]              INT
);

INSERT INTO @Data
(
    [ID],
    [MONTHS],
    [THIS_MONTH_VALUE],
    [SUM]
)
VALUES
(1, 0, 'NEW', 4987),
(2, 1, 'ACTIVE', 3849),
(3, 1, 'CHURN', 1138),
(4, 1, 'NEW', 884),
(5, 2, 'ACTIVE', 3821),
(6, 2, 'CHURN', 912),
(7, 2, 'NEW', 818),
(9, 3, 'ACTIVE', 3954),
(10, 3, 'CHURN', 942);

-- the following statement should work in any RDBMS but you might have to change
-- the square brackets to whatever your RDBMS uses to escape

SELECT [d1].[ID],
       [d1].[MONTHS],
       [d1].[THIS_MONTH_VALUE],
       [d1].[SUM],
       [d2].[ID],
       [d2].[MONTHS],
       [d2].[THIS_MONTH_VALUE],
       [d2].[SUM],
       1.0 * [d1].[SUM] / [d2].[SUM] AS [CHURN_RATE]
FROM   @Data AS [d1]
       INNER JOIN @Data AS [d2]
           ON [d1].[THIS_MONTH_VALUE] = 'CHURN'
              AND [d2].[THIS_MONTH_VALUE] = 'ACTIVE'
              AND [d2].[MONTHS] = [d1].[MONTHS] - 1;
```

The output is:

| ID | MONTHS | THIS_MONTH_VALUE | SUM | ID | MONTHS | THIS_MONTH_VALUE | SUM | CHURN_RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2 | CHURN | 912 | 2 | 1 | ACTIVE | 3849 | 0.236944660950 |
| 10 | 3 | CHURN | 942 | 5 | 2 | ACTIVE | 3821 | 0.246532321381 |

Again, you might have to modify the query to get exactly what you want.

Comment: You nailed it. I was able to figure it out this morning using the same methodology. Pretty proud of myself ngl. Thanks a million.

Comment: Glad you figured it out @MikeyKramer - if you wouldn't mind, mark this is an answer so others will find it easily. Thanks!